# Merging Dataframes but losing Data

Tags: python

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A has 5 columns (the first one being tickers) and Dataframe B has 2 columns (the first one being tickers). They are of different lengths. I am trying to add a 6th column to dataframe A based on matching the tickers. Not all the tickers are in dataframe B and when using the merge function I am losing those tickers. How do I keep all the data I already have in dataframe A and add a column, perhaps filling the space where the ticker is not found in dataframe B with NaN.

Answer (score 1):

As you can find on the [pandas.DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), there are many parameters you can use in order to perform the merging that suits you best. In this case, the one you're looking for is the **how='outer'**, which makes a union of both DataFrames, adding columns of both ones.

```
DataframeA.merge(DataFrameB, how='outer')
```